# How do I implement a tri-state buffer for a vector in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, buffer, tri-state

I want to implement a tri-state buffer for a input vector, triggered by an enable vector, where every bit of the enable vector enables the corresponding bit of the input vector.

Something like this but with multiple enable bits:

[image: A 4 bit tri-state buffer but with a single enable bit.]

A single tri-state buffer looks like this:

```
Y <= A when (EN = '0') else 'Z';
```

(example from: https://startingelectronics.org/software/VHDL-CPLD-course/tut16-tri-state-buffer/ )

It could look like this (but that one doesn't work...):

```
[...]
signal Y : std_logic_vector(N downto 0);
signal A : std_logic_vector(N downto 0);
signal EN : std_logic_vector(N downto 0);

Y <= A when EN = (others => '1') else (others => 'Z');
```

Is there a way to declare this in VHDL or do I have to write a buffer for every bit?

Edit:
To clarify I'm searching a short declaration for this:

```
Y(0) <= A(0) when EN(0) = '1' else 'Z';
Y(1) <= A(1) when EN(1) = '1' else 'Z';
[...]
Y(N) <= A(N) when EN(N) = '1' else 'Z';
```

Comment: You have to tell us what "doesn't work" means. A couple of notes: (1) EN can be a single std_logic. (2) Then `Y <= A when EN = '0' else (A'range => 'Z');` ought to work. (3) Using `A'range` attribute instead of `others` makes the size of the vector explicit which will help in places where the compiler can't tell the correct range for `others`.

Comment: `OTHERS choice used in aggregate for unconstrained record or array type is not supported` that example should only demonstrate what I meant. 
Yes that works but it enables the complete vector. I'm searching for a compact way to describe this:
`Y(0) <= A(0) when EN(0) = '1' else 'Z';`
`Y(1) <= A(1) when EN(1) = '1' else 'Z';`
[...]
`Y(N) <= A(N) when EN(N) = '1' else 'Z';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need enable control for each bit, then the easiest way is to use a generate statement:

```vhdl
tristate : for i in 0 to N generate
begin
    Y(i) <= A(i) when EN(i) = '1' else 'Z';
end generate tristate;
```

Generate statements with `for` constraints create multiple circuits which operate in parallel, unlike a for loop in programming where the same code is executed multiple times in series.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost nailed it. Try this

```vhdl
signal Y : std_logic_vector(N downto 0);
signal A : std_logic_vector(N downto 0);
signal EN : std_logic;

Y <= A when EN = '1' else (others => 'Z');
```

Comment: yes but here's only one enable bit. I would like to have an enable vector.